# Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (starting new Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, out-of-memory

My application contains more than 5 activities with backgrounds services. When I run the app and I click on a button to create the second Activity, the app crashes.

Thanks for any help.

my xml layout : 
[image]

Here is my onCreate:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apollo.arrroo/com.example.apollo.arrroo.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at com.example.apollo.arrroo.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5254)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at com.example.apollo.arrroo.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5254) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1969)
                                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                                           at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3348)
                                                                           at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3285)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:421)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:187)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at com.example.apollo.arrroo.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11) 
 // even more
```

Comment: post the xml code please

Comment: i have  posted the xml

Comment: just to make sure please remove that background and check if the error keeps or not

Comment: you can also use photoshop to reduce the image and use this to generate all images to all screens you want https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: I solved the problem if you have the out of memory because of the large image (jpeg) you must use the software FormatFactory. first  you see  in left  : (picture )click on it  and chose: all to jpg ---&-click on --  output setting  & choose (max width1024 max height 768). & finally click on add file choose your image from desktop and click ok . and click on start .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background image's file size is too large. I don't know what your structure looks like but `gogo1` should probably have several different resolutions based on screen sizes. Not only that but it should be mobile optimized so that it can be loaded efficiently (and avoid out of memory exceptions).

If you must load the image and cannot compress the file size then your only option would be to set the background programmatically after compressing the drawable to a size that won't cause an out of memory exception.

My recommendation is fix `gogo1` so the image is optimized for different screen sizes and also make sure it's file size is no more than ~100kb (and even that is overkill).

Comment: your answer  impressed me . just tell me what i must use to optimise my image . and thank you

Comment: Please provide the image dimensions. Maybe you can resize it to avoid the OOM exception.

Comment: one question . what generaly android devlopers use to reduce the image size to avoid out of memory ?

Comment: I'd recommend just not using a background image for an entire view, set it to a solid color that you defined in `colors.xml`. If you are doing a splash screen then do the same thing, set the background color and then add an `ImageView` to load the image but make sure it's cropped to only the relevant image.

Comment: yes i agree with you but . please i need a complet answer how i can do that . for example what you use (code or photoshop .... )  when you create  an app to resize imageview to avoid (out of memory) ?? i need  you to write how dont just answer please ????

Comment: I don't know what the image looks like so it's literally impossible for me to give a complete example. If you are doing a solid color background then it's enough to just add something like `android:background="@color/white"` if you wanted to have a white background. Likewise if you were going to still use the image then I would recommend resizing in Photoshop or another image editor to cut down on the file size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem if you have the out of memory because of the large image (jpeg) you must use the software FormatFactory. first  you see  in left  : (picture )click on it  and chose: all to jpg ---&-click on --  output setting  & choose (max width1024 max height 768). & finally click on add file choose your image from desktop and click ok . and click on start .